# SASS on Sublime Text 3 - [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Tags: windows, character-encoding, sass, sublimetext3

I've been trying to use sass in sublime text 3 today and for that I installed Ruby, Ruby SASS gem and the Sublime packages Sass and Sass Build. All seems to be working well but when I try to build the css file (using the Sass Build package) I get this weird error:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['sass', '--update', 'F:\\Program Files (x86)\\wamp\\www\\singlepage\\wp-content\\themes\\manaca\\style.scss:F:\\Program Files (x86)\\wamp\\www\\singlepage\\wp-content\\themes\\manaca/style.css', '--stop-on-error', '--no-cache', '--style', 'compressed']]
[dir: F:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\singlepage\wp-content\themes\manaca]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\Program Files (x86)\MacType;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\]
```

And when I try to build the compressed CSS (from the same package) it simply returns

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

What's been bugging me is the crazy file paths returned in the last line (shouldn't even be searching in C: )

The other thing I've been researching about is the `output not utf-8` thing. Even if I specify the charset on my sass (or scss) file, the problem lingers.

Anyway, I appreciate any type of help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around the problem.

The path thing was a missing step of my Ruby installation on Windows. I needed to register Ruby's path in Environment Variables.

But still the package Sass Build wasn't working so I opened cmd and told Sass to watch the file, inside my website folder:

```
cd "program files (x86)\..\mysite"
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compact --no-cache
```

Now every time I save the style.scss file the css file is updated properly.

Hope that clarifies the process to anyone else!

Answer (score 4):

`"shell": true` - this is the key.

If I try build-system like this (on WinXP):

```
{
    "cmd": ["ant", "-f", "project-build.xml"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

I get:
`[Decode error - output not utf-8]`
because `cmd` should be `"ant.bat"` instead.
Sublime is looking for file exacly called `ant` and encoding of `"file does not exist"` message is not utf-8.
When I use shell like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["ant", "-f", "project-build.xml"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "shell": true
}
```

everything works fine (even without `"windows": { "cmd": ....}` ) because shell searches for `ant.exe` and then `ant.bat`.

Comment: Great solution - and explanation for the weird "not utf-8" message.

Answer (score 1):

Just a reference for people who had similar problem and the accepted answer didn't help:

I had a similar error, in my case I had to install python and add it to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

add ruby to envirement variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error when I open Sublime Text from a console window. Open Sublime from a normal shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone else comes across this on a different matter, I was building a project in openCL (using C API not C++) and encountered this error.

Turns out I hadn't allocated enough memory for the string to hold the program build log.

Comment: How is this related to Sass or Sublime Text?

Comment: Not related to Sass, but was an error with Sublime Text build system not being to display the output error - just gave that error. (just was stuck on this for quite a while and someone may stumble upon this page with the same problem)