# Why does Sublime Text report that my program terminates with exit code 1?

Tags: c, compilation, sublimetext2

I was using Sublime Text to compile a code I made, but it gave me this error:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I though it was because I didn't save it to UTF-8, but when I save with UTF-8 it gives me the same error. I tried to compile it using IdeOne, it compiles fine, but it gives Time limit exceeded, but this is because of the code. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int x, d;
    for(x=1;  ; x++){
        for(d = 2; d <= 20; d++){
            if(x%d != 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(d == 21){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It may seem it has an infinite loop but it didn't.

Comment: C, pure C... I don't like C++

Comment: You can surely make a better title, I believe.

Comment: Don't add C++ tag to your C questions!

Comment: C source should be saved as ASCII to be on the safe side  (a compiler may or may not support UTF-8)

Comment: also, it'd be good to end your output with a `'\n'`

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: M.M, I don't need it on this program, because I just want one output.

Comment: @M.M: The code is UTF-8 and 8-bit-ASCII compatible, because it does not contain any special characters (i.e. bit 7 == 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

https://gist.github.com/clijiac/2814161
[SASS on Sublime Text 3 - [Decode error - output not utf-8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068832/sass-on-sublime-text-3-decode-error-output-not-utf-8)
[Sublime Text 3, Python 3 and UTF-8 don't like each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other)
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7809

A possibility is that it might be missing the directory of the compiler in the PATH variable. So, to do that, go to:

Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings

Click on "Ambient Variables" and add the path on the system variable "PATH".

Answer (score 2):

Your program is fine but it takes a while (2.3s on my computer, yours might be slower) to terminate which is the reason why IdeOne complains. The first `x` to satisfy your test is `232792560`.

Comment: I've undone the act of marking as answer, because there are people saying this is the answer for my question about the error.

Comment: @MoonWalker As you like. I don't mind, I have enough reputation.

Comment: I would like you to answer to my problem plz. As I can see you are very good.

Comment: @MoonWalker What problem remains? I'm not really familiar with Sublime Text (and I won't buy it to answer a question), I can't tell you why you observe the behaviour you observe.

Comment: You don't need to buy it. But thanks for your help. I've solved the problem myself. I'll post my answer

Comment: @MoonWalker Great! I love people who post answer to their own questions.